# Loading Same View with posted data by user if ModelState.IsValid returns false

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to MVC and I will try to elaborate my issue carefully.
I have a controller with 2 Action Methods, one of which is a POST method:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    RegisterViewModel registerModel = new RegisterViewModel();
    //Some Code to populate dropdowns for user to select
    return View(registerModel);
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //insert data in tables
            RedirectToAction("Register");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error Processing Your Request");
    }

    // If ModelState.IsValid returns false show the form with posted data by user
    return RedirectToAction("Register", model);
}
```

Now when form is posted all the data filled by user is not persisted.
I want to display the same form to user with his posted data and fill
missing details to complete registration.

Sorry if this is a very basic question. How do I persist the data on the same view.

Comment: If its invalid, then you use `return View(model);` to return the view and display the validation errors (not `RedirectToAction(...)`)

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Register", model) calls the same function again

Comment: I also have EditorTemplate which loads on the view and when I            return View(model); Then I get the error as  **The ViewData item that has the key 'EmploymentType' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.**

Comment: Please start a new question for that, because that is not directly related to the subject matter of this question.

Comment: Gotcha Thanks a lot

Comment: For that error, refer [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366305/the-viewdata-item-that-has-the-key-xxx-is-of-type-system-int32-but-must-be-o) - you need to repopulate  and SelectLists used in your view before you return it

Answer (score 2):

First Edit Your Model With **DataAnnotations [Required]** which You don't want to be empty like:

        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Name Can't be Empty.")] 
        public string Name { get; set; }

Now edit your controller some thing like.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  //insert data in tables
      RedirectToAction("Register");
}
else
{
return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `return RedirectToAction("Register", model);` use `return View(model);`.

[Here](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/return-view-vs-return-redirecttoaction-vs-return-redirect-vs-return-redirecttoroute) is a nice blog explaining the differences.